# Showing whether $\tau=\inf\{t:X_t=\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}X_t\}$ is a stopping time or not

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance, stopping-times

As the title suggests, I am not sure how to show if $\tau=\inf\{t:X_t=\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}X_t\}$ is a stopping time or not, where $\{X_t\}$ is an adapted process. Intuitively, I see that it is not a stopping time from the finance context — if $X_t$ refers to stock price and we want to exercise an American call option, then if $\tau$ was a stopping time this would contradict the assertion that early exercise of an American call option is not optimal. However, this is as far I can go, as my intuition tells me this is not in $\mathcal{F}_t$ generated by $X_t$, but how should I start proving this rigorously, and a bigger concern is what about $\mathcal{F}_{t^+}$? Would be nice to see in particular for the geometric Brownian motion case too.

(NB: I am asking this in the Math SE instead of QF SE as I am searching for a more mathematical justification, but I am placing my American option argument in here for some context.)

Comment: As an intuitive explanation, $\tau$ is a stopping time if the decision to stop at some time $t$ is based only on information available at time $t$, not on any future information. This is evidently not true for the stopping time that you defined.

Comment: Without further assumption (e.g., continuity of sample paths), $\sup_{0\leq t \leq T} X_t$ needs not be measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\tau$ is a stopping time.

I will assume $X$ Brownian motion so that it's clearer.

Since $0 \leq \tau \leq T$, we can you the optional stopping time theorem and say that $\mathbb{E}[X_\tau] = \mathbb{E}[X_0] = 0$.

However, it's clear that $X_\tau > 0$ almost surely, so we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Ah I didn’t realise this was a sufficient proof! I thought I was going to have to consider the set of particular times or something. Thanks! Is $X_\tau>0$ a.s. assuming it is a GBM? Also, does this only apply to the filtration generated by $X_t$, or does this extend to the augmented right-continuous ones as well? In the finance context, I would assume that the right-continuous case means you know if you know the stock price will decrease at $\tau^+$, making it a stopping time?

Comment: Any filtration is ok, and it's positive because it's a brownian motion! In the GBM context, the result would still be true, but a small additional part would be necessary (you'd get $\mathbb{E}[X_\tau] = 1$, $X_\tau \geq 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_\tau > 1) > 0$)

Comment: Isn’t geometric Brownian motion a submartingale though? Would it then not be possible to use optional stopping like this?

Comment: I was thinking about the case with $r=0$, case in which it works